# gsl_interp2d.h and gsl_spline2d not found in standard installation of gsl

Tags: c++, interpolation, gsl

I downloaded gsl-1.15 from

[www.gnu.org/software/gsl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)

and wanted to try the 2d-interpolation example

[2D-Interpolation-Example-programs](http:////https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/2D-Interpolation-Example-programs.html#g_t2D-Interpolation-Example-programs)

However, it turns out that neither `gsl_interp2d.h` nor `gsl_spline2d.h` do  exist.
The same happens if i emerge `sci-libs/gsl` on my gentoo machine.

Can anybody tell me how to obtain `interp2d.h` and friends?

Comment: 2D interpolation is not implemented in 1.15 version. Download 1.16 and beyond

Comment: This seems not to be true - i downloaded  gsl-1.16.tar.gz  from www.gnu.org/software/gsl, but this did contain neither of the two header files.

Comment: My Mistake - it was added in version 2.1 - see NEWS section ( look for the sentence added bilinear and bicubic interpolation (David Zaslavsky))